# Mustache Dynamically set variable

Tags: javascript, mustache

I need help in using a javascript variable set dynamically as my mustache template variable. Here is the problem. My JSON looks like this

```
jsonData = {
"recipemodules" : {
    "enchiladas" : [
        {
            "title" : "Chicken Enchiladas",
            "thumbnailurl" : "http:www.google.com/image",
            "recipelink" : "location to recipe",
            "credit" : "some credit"
        },
        {
            "title" : "Chicken Enchiladas",
            "thumbnailurl" : "http:www.google.com/image",
            "recipelink" : "location to recipe",
            "credit" : "some credit"
        }
    ],
    "roastchicken" : [
        {
            "title" : "Chicken Enchiladas",
            "thumbnailurl" : "http:www.google.com/image",
            "recipelink" : "location to recipe",
            "credit" : "some credit"
        },
        {
            "title" : "Chicken Enchiladas",
            "thumbnailurl" : "http:www.google.com/image",
            "recipelink" : "location to recipe",
            "credit" : "some credit"
        }
    ],
    "salmon" : [
        {
            "title" : "salmon ",
            "thumbnailurl" : "http:www.google.com/image",
            "recipelink" : "location to recipe",
            "credit" : "some credit"
        },
        {
            "title" : "Chicken Enchiladas",
            "thumbnailurl" : "http:www.google.com/image",
            "recipelink" : "location to recipe",
            "credit" : "some credit"
        }

    ]
}
```

};

Then what i am doing next is... going to a webpage...grabing the URL and based on that URL, I set a variable.

```js
var theCurrentURL = window.location.href;
var finalJSONobject = "";

switch(theCurrentURL) {
 case "www.google.com/something1":
  finalJSONobject = "enchiladas";
  break;
 case "www.google.com/something2":
  finalJSONobject = "roastchicken";
  break;
 case "www.google.com/something3":
  finalJSONobject = "salmon";
  break;
 default:
}
```

Finally... here is what my mushtache template looks like

```js
// create template
template = '{{#enchiladas}}<div class="mri-container"><img src="{{thumbnailurl}}" /></div>{{/enchiladas}}';
 // parse template
 Mustache.parse(template);
 // render template
 rendered = Mustache.render(template, jsonData.recipemodules);
      
 // inject template to DOM
 carousel.html(rendered);
```

Now it runs fine when i use {{#enchiladas}}{{/enchiladas}} ... but this is not what i want. i want to be able to use a variable name instead of enchiladas.

if you look at my switch statement... it returns finalJSONobject as a string. i want my template to look like

```
template = '{{#finalJSONobject}}<div class="mri-container"><img src="{{thumbnailurl}}" /></div>{{/finalJSONobject}}';
```

But this does not work. The mustache template is using jsonData.recipemodules as its data. Therefore jsonData.recipemodules.enchiladas will work... but i want to dynamically set "enchiladas" which is set on my switch statement. I want to use my dynamically set variable in the template. i want to use jsonData.recipemodules.finalJSONobject so that based on the page... i look the data i want.

Please help me! thank you so much.

Konstantin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking to the wrong direction here. You could just pass another variable to `render` instead of `jsonData.recipemodules` if you want your last template to work.
To illustrate that:

```
// jsonData definition before this
var theCurrentURL = window.location.href;
var templateData = {};

switch(theCurrentURL) {
    case "www.google.com/something1":
        templateData.finalJSONobject = jsonData.recipeModules["enchiladas"];
        break;
    case "www.google.com/something2":
        templateData.finalJSONobject = jsonData.recipeModules["roastchicken"];
        break;
    case "www.google.com/something3":
        templateData.finalJSONobject = jsonData.recipeModules["salmon"];
        break;
    default:
}
// create template
template = '{{#finalJSONobject}}<div class="mri-container"><img src="{{thumbnailurl}}" /></div>{{/finalJSONobject}}';
 // parse template
 Mustache.parse(template);
 // render template
 rendered = Mustache.render(template, templateData);

 // inject template to DOM
 carousel.html(rendered);
```

Comment: Matias... thank you so much. I could hug you right now!! Its working now. Thank you thank yooooou!